# Estimating the norm over the boundary by the norm over the domain

Tags: partial-differential-equations, normed-spaces, boundary-value-problem

Consider a harmonic function $u$ on a bounded domain $\Omega$ with the Dirichlet boundary $u = g$ on $\partial \Omega$. Let us say that $u \in C^{k,\alpha}(\Omega)$. Why is it that $|u|_{k,\alpha, \partial\Omega}$ can be absorbed by the norm $|u|_{k,\alpha, \Omega}$? Is this always the case over bounded domains for the Dirichlet problem?

Comment: What's the definition of $|u|_{k,\alpha, \partial\Omega}$?

Comment: For smooth enough functions $u$ (up to the boundary), $|u|_{k,\alpha,\partial\Omega} = \sum_{|j|<l} \sup_{\partial\Omega} |D^ju(x)| + \sum_{|j| = [l]} \sup_{x,y \in \partial \Omega} \frac{D^ju(x)-D^ju(y)}{|x-y|^{l-[l]}}$.